# PDO php mysql multiple requests

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm using Slim framework to provide an API to our clients. I'm focused on Java so that could the the point, because the problem is related with database connection.

Every request connect to the database throw PDO like

```
 $dbh = new PDO($param1, $param2, $param3);//php 7.1
```

So as php don't have a connection pool i understand each request (maybe at the same time) starts a new connection throw the database.

**But i'm experimenting a kind of situation here.**

**If one request starts a transaction for inserting or updating something, next requests will wait until this transaction finish, but it is on a different thread, so i'm thinking on table locks? or something like each request is getting the same connection.**

***THE PROBLEM:***

> So if they are in different threads with a different connection how
>   they need to wait until transaction ends for the first request.

My database source class is something like

```
class DataBaseConfig {
    public static function getConn()
    {                
        $dbh = new PDO($param1, $param2, $param3);
        $dbh->exec("set names utf8");
        return $dbh;
    }
}
```

And i use it like

```
$db = DataBaseConfig::getConn();
$db->beginTransaction();
//code
$db->commit();
```

I'm missing something sure, so can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

> NEWS! EDIT
>
> @YourCommonSense thank you it was finally a session configuration. I
>   didn't know that php start_session(); locks the session file so that's
>   what was happening. Thanks a lot!
>   link: https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/

Comment: Which problem?.

Comment: `So as php don't have a connection pool ` - really? Where did you get that info? I always find it interesting when people think PHP can't maintain persistent connections and believe that on every request PHP opens a new connection - yet, that's completely incorrect. You're trying to solve a problem that you don't even have.

Comment: @Mjh your rant, although being correct by itself, is irrelevant to the OP's imaginary problem

Comment: @Mjh Well, on google. but i'm not expert on php so if that is wrong maybe you can help me with it. Some information about conenction pool pdo php?

Comment: Patrick, how's your PHP served? Apache with `mod_php` or is your web server talking to PHP via FastCGI?

Comment: @Mjh persistent connections won't help him, if you care to read the whole question, instead of picking on a single keyword

Comment: So I still fail to see a problem here. Do you have any *real* problem at hand?

Comment: @Mjh yes, Apache and fastCGI. i'm using php-fpm

Comment: @YourCommonSense - you're quite funny, calling me out for something you're doing. Can you stop highlighting me? It's annoying, I'd like to speak to OP and not you, as you're incapable of reading with comprehension.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the problem is if a user must wait for a transaction end, on a simple select on the database why? i'm writing on another table on the first request for example and a read in different one on the second request. So why second request must wait for the first one to end the transaction?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - which part of "can you stop highliging me" was unclear to you? There's plenty of kid-related sites like 4 chan, please go play there.

Comment: @Patrick since you're using Apache, you might be experiencing it's "optimization" step where it won't let your 2nd request start until 1st one is finished loading. This is a known issue, it's not related to PHP nor MySQL. Have you experienced that maybe, which lead you to believe that one PHP process is waiting for another to finish?

Comment: @YourCommonSense My testing example.

Comment: @Mjh the apache is serving all in different threads. It appears ok

Comment: @Patrick yes, it is, internally. But OS and Apache are pipelining multiple requests through a single one (this is prior to HTTP2). This often causes an adverse effect where users can't open two (or more) tabs and load the same page until 1st tab finishes loading.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - no problem, updating my CV as we speak, thanks for the review. Anything else I've no clue about? I really appreciate your input, without this I'd be left in this delusion that I did know, but luckily you came to my rescue. My hero!

Comment: as @YourCommonSense commented before, i think now it's related with php sessions. https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/